# Conflicts with sonata admin bundle and LiipFunctionalTestBundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, liipfunctionaltestbundle

when I try to install sonata admin and LiipFunctionalTestBundle, it gives me a validator problem,

> FileLoaderLoadException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to           Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin::setValidator() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidatorInterface, instance of Liip\FunctionalTestBundle\Validator\DataCollectingValidator given, called in /var/www/app.gyman/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 713 and defined in /var/www/app.gyman/app/config/. (which is being imported from "/var/www/app.gyman/app/config/routing.yml").

and I found some propositions to install sonata dev master, when i do that,

```
"sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
"sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
"sonata-project/block-bundle": "dev-master",
"sonata-project/core-bundle": "dev-master",
"knplabs/knp-menu-bundle":"*"
```

It gives me this errors:

> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by
>   sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle[dev-master].
>       - Can only install one of: sonata-project/core-bundle[dev-master, 2.x-dev].
>       - sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle dev-master requires sonata-project/core-bundle ^2.3.1 -> satisfiable by
>   sonata-project/core-bundle[2.x-dev].
>       - Installation request for sonata-project/core-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sonata-project/core-bundle[dev-master].

Comment: I put your configuration in a `composer.json` file and the installation fail, it looks like it's not related to LiipFunctionalTestBundle and it comes from Sonata bundles.

Comment: so you have any propositions to solve that ? i tried many versions of sonata ,but same error always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `3.0.0` version of SonataAdminBundle has been released [6 days ago](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/3731#issuecomment-217414161). But it looks like there was a problem with SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle that has been fixed [two days ago](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle/issues/546#issuecomment-218221655), it is now available on [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle#3.0.0).

It is now possible to use these versions of the Sonata packages:

```
{
    "require": {
        "sonata-project/core-bundle": "3.0.*",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "3.0.*",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "3.0.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "liip/functional-test-bundle": "~1.6"
    }
}
```

And the installation works:

```
$ composer update --no-interaction --no-progress
[…]
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
[…]
  - Installing sonata-project/core-bundle (3.0.0)
[…]
  - Installing sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle (3.0.0)
[…]
  - Installing liip/functional-test-bundle (1.6.3)
[…]
```

---

There was some problems with the dependencies and it was impossible to install the Sonata bundles, see these comments from my previous answer I have deleted since:

> I have tried many versions and still have the same problem than you, it looks like the Sonata bundles are broken… – A.L May 3 at 18:06

> Exactly, we must wait some days, hoping that can be solved with this versions – Nada May 3 at 20:34

Comment: @Nada Did you try this solution?

Answer (score 1):

Solved with an older version of Liip Functional test bundle
, my new composer is as following:

```
           "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0"

    "sonata-project/core-bundle": "~2.2",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.2",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "~2.2",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "~2.1",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "2.1.7"

},
"require-dev": {
    "liip/functional-test-bundle": "1.0.2",
```